# Launch an application in another X-session as non-root

Tags: linux, xorg

How to start an X server as root with a session of non-root application?

Should be something like

```
xinit 'su -c openbox user' -- :1
```

but working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be that the only way is to create temporary `.xinitrc` file. Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

username="$USER"
let xdisplay=${DISPLAY:1}+1

# Temporary xinitrc
temp_xinit="$(tempfile -p '.xinit' -s 'rc')" || exit
trap "rm -f -- '$temp_xinit'" EXIT

# Launch X
echo "sudo -u $username $@" > "$temp_xinit"
sudo xinit "$temp_xinit" -- :$xdisplay
```

Example usage:

```
$ Xnew.sh /usr/local/games/braid [..options...]
```

Comment: It would be better to use `mktemp`, part of _coreutils_, instead of `tempfile`.

Comment: @kolypto when I use it the application I wanted to run (e.g. /usr/local/games/braid) indeed run as the user but the X server itself runs as root. Did you find a way to run both as your user (most important the XServer)? thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
su -c 'startx openbox -- :1' user
```

*Edit*: Also try running

```
X :1 &
su -c 'DISPLAY=:1 openbox &' user
```

Comment: It's possible if 'startx' is allowed to be launched as unprivileged user. Otherwise, it gives "X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting."

Comment: @o_O: My system (Arch Linux) appears to have `/usr/bin/Xorg` setuid-root.